# Reload systemd/gunicorn/flask worker threads sequentially for config changes

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, systemd

I need to force an app reload to pick up config changes. I'm using systemd to kick of gunicorn that runs a flask app.

I pick up the config changes in a /var/run/xx.conf file, which is watched by a systemd/service/app.path:

```
[Path]
PathChanged=/var/run/app.conf

[Unit]
Description=app-restart
```

and a corresponding app.system:

```
[Unit]
Description=app-restart
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
PIDFile=/run/app-restart/pid
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/app-reload.py
PrivateTmp=false
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/environment

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The question is - how to gracefully terminate each gunicorn flask worker thread?

The app's systemd service uses:

```
[Unit]
Description=app gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
PIDFile=/run/app/pid
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/opt/app
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:/var/tmp/app.sock -m 007 --workers=2  -t 400 --backlog 2048 --log-config=/etc/app/log.cfg --log-level=DEBUG app
Restart=always
RestartSec=15
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=false
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/environment

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

so that I can kill off gunicorn worker threads and they will be restarted.

I would like to avoid killing off threads that are in the process of handling repsonses.

Ideally, after each response if handled, the thread would check whether it needs to quit or not. I know I can do this in each and every flask API method, but is there a better way of transitioning all worker threads to the new config one at a time?

I don't want to `sysctl restart app.service` as that kills off all threads and creates a dead time where there are no workers active.
I want each tread to terminate and reload independently so there's always some live workers.

Some options I've considered:

1. get a list of app pids with app-reload.py and kill them off one at a time. Gunicorn will restart each as it dies. May terminate an in-progress request.
2. After each event handled, check for existance of  file, that is created by app-reload.py, and if present, terminate.

I'm assuming there must be a way to migrate workers from one config to the other without creating a service dead spot.

Answer (score 1):

RTM wins again.

http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/signals.html

> HUP: Reload the configuration, start the new worker processes with a
>   new configuration and gracefully shutdown older workers. If the
>   application is not preloaded (using the preload_app option), Gunicorn
>   will also load the new version of it.

So the end result is just this in the systemd app.path:

```
[Unit]
Description=app-restart
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
Group=root
ExecStart=/bin/kill -s HUP $(cat /run/app/pid)
PrivateTmp=false
```

Alternately, one could also rely on the fact that the app.system contains an ExecReload line and use:

```
ExecReload=/bin/systemctl reload app
```